# How do I specify the calling contract account address when writing a truufle test case？

Tags: solidity, truffle

**step3.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract step3 {
    
  address owner; // 状态变量

  constructor() {
      owner = msg.sender;
  }
    
  function sayHello() external view returns(address a){
      if(owner==msg.sender) {
        return msg.sender;
      }

      string memory  greeting ="hello world"; // 局部变量
      
      return msg.sender;
  }

}
```

**cehck.js**

```
//执行定义变量来表示不同的合约
const step3  = artifacts.require('step3.sol');
//执行定义合约中的其他操作
contract('step3',accounts => {
    before(async () => {
      let a = await step3.deployed();
      let c = await a.sayHello();
      console.log("调用greets 方法：入参：无，回参："+c);
      console.log(accounts)
    });
    it('Check whether the contract has been issued successfully', async () => {
    }); 
});
```

I tried to get the default contract address using truffle and I succeeded, I now need to change the contract account address for calling the contract in truffle

Answer (score 0):

Since your `sayhello()` is a `view` function, Truffle framework makes a read-only call by default. Read-only calls can simply override the `from` parameter without having to know the private key of the sender.

```
let c = await a.sayHello({from: ownerAddress});
```